# trsnsition of array betwen two particular function javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

I am on **javascript** by recently and i have a problem with xmlhttprequest.
The function gets values from another php file and with  `documet.getElementById ('demo'). InnerHtml`  returns the value that want,  on **html**. And here is ok.

But i want to save this value in a variable and use this variable in another function (always **javascript**).

With two classic function i haven't nothing problem, but betwween function **xml**... and, in this case, a function for print the google map, i'm blocked. All functions are in the same file.

P.S.: talk of Variable but is an **array**. But problem don't change.
if don't understand something, or i've did errors correct me.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1**

Tanks for welcome. The next questions will put you better. Now I hope I have clarified the situation better. The first function retrieves the array and with innerhtml i can print the result. But I would like to use the array in the second function and I do not know how to do it

first function:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = state;
function state() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  for( i=0; i < variabile_js; i++){
    for( j=0; j < 2; j++){
      myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      //document.write(myArr);
      }
    }
  documet.getElementById ('demo').InnerHtml = myArr;
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "dati_new2.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

second function:

```
function myMap() {
var lat, lon;
var locations;
var marker, i;
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25);
var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
var mapOptions = {center: myCenter, zoom: 10};
var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:myCenter});
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ maxWidth: 100 });

for (i = 0; i < variabile_js; i++) {  
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(Arr[i][1], Arr[i][2]),
        map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i){
        return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(Arr[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
        return;
     })(marker, i));
   }
}
```

Comment: It is extremely hard/ impossible to diagnose your problem with a poor description and no code example.

Comment: Post code of these two functions and the call you tried to make and that failed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a look at [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: To return and use a value from an Ajax request you will need to think about using `Promises` ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise )

Comment: I added some more detail to the question. Then the next one will write them better